# проблема с кодировкой BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, beautiful-soup, bs4

Написал код, как советовали здесь для парсера `xml` файла.

Но я так понимаю выходит проблема с кодировкой или я не правильно понял.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

infile = open('C:\\Users\\inikitatech\\Python Example\\xml_data.xml', 'r')
contents = infile.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, 'xml')

print(soup.select_one('id').text)
print(soup.select_one('href').text.strip())
print(soup.select_one('url').text.strip())
```

Выходит вот такая ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/inikitatech/PycharmProjects/PythonExample/ZakupParser.py", line 4, in <module>
    contents = infile.read()
  File "C:\Users\inikitatech\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\encodings\cp1251.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 739: character maps to <undefined>
```

Посмотрел как можно было решить данную проблему. Пишут что можно решить данную проблему при помощи встроенной библиотеки `codecs`, но выходит уже другая ошибка.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import codecs

infile = codecs.open('C:\\Users\\inikitatech\\Python Example\\xml_data.xml', 'r', 'utf-8')
contents = infile.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, 'xml')

print(soup.select_one('id').text)
print(soup.select_one('href').text.strip())
print(soup.select_one('url').text.strip())
```

Вот такая ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/inikitatech/PycharmProjects/PythonExample/ZakupParser.py", line 6, in <module>
    soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, 'xml')
  File "C:\Users\inikitatech\PycharmProjects\PythonExample\venv\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 165, in __init__
    % ",".join(features))
bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: xml. Do you need to install a parser library?
```

Что это значит и как все-таки нормально распарсить `xml`?

Comment: `soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, 'html.parser')` или ``soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, 'lxml')``

Comment: @gil9red помогла. я так понял для этого не нужно импортировать библиотеку lxml.

Comment: Не, BeautifulSoup сам попробует импортиртировать указанный парсер

Comment: @gil9red можешь подсказать где- то используется .text, а где-то .text.strip(). В чем разница?

Comment: `.text` возвращает текст из элемента, а `strip()` метод строк для удаления слева и справа пустых символов, типо: пробелы, табуляции, переводы на следующую строку. т.е. если `.text` вернет строку `"  text\n  \n"`, то strip ее укоротит до `"text"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Автору помогло указание правильного парсера:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, 'html.parser')
```

или

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, 'lxml')
```